# Says that object has no attribute when it has

Tags: python, python-3.x

python (3.4.0)

pygame (pygame-1.9.3-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64)

```
import pygame
from pygame import *
init()
display.set_mode((500,500))
gameExit = False
while not gameExit:
    for event in event.get():
        print(event)
    display.update()
```

When a run it the pygame window opens normally, but i get this:

```
<Event(17-VideoExpose {})>
<Event(16-VideoResize {'h': 500, 'size': (500, 500), 'w': 500})>
<Event(1-ActiveEvent {'gain': 0, 'state': 1})>
<Event(4-MouseMotion {'buttons': (0, 0, 0), 'rel': (500, 309), 'pos': (499, 
308)})>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\a_2.py", line 7, in <module>
    for event in event.get():
AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'get'
```

How object has no attribute if i set the:

```
from pygame import *
```

???????

OBS: when i import only:

```
import pygame
```

and put pygame. before every pygame function it works

thanks for any help ^^

Comment: This is a good example of why you should avoid using global imports. The `pygame.event` object and the `pygame.event.Event` object names are conflicting.  Use `for event in pygame.event.get()`.

Comment: I'm not sure about the specific module but one approach is to change the for loop to `for e in event: print(e)` and find out what kind of objects come out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the same variable name. It is being overwritten on the first iteration:

```
for event in event.get():
```

When this for loop starts executing it rebinds the name `event` to an object that does not have a `get()` method. Hence the problem.

Try something like:

```
for ev in event.get():
    print(ev)
```

Also, avoid `import *`. Then you could write:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    print(event)
```